# iOS Sprite Kit - SKSpriteNode - blend two sprites

Tags: sprite-kit

Actually, I'm migrating a game from another platform, and I need to generate a sprite with two images.
The first image will be something like the form, a pattern or stamp, and the second is only a rectangle that sets color to the first. If the color was plane, it will be easy, I could use sprite.color and sprite.colorBlendFactor to play with it, but there are levels where the second image is a rectangle with two colors (red and green, for example).
Is there any way to implement these with Sprite Kit?
I mean, something like using Core image filter, and CIBlendWithAlphaMask, but only with Image and Mask image. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346) -> CIBlendWithAlphaMask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the `SKCropNode` class (documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCropNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKCropNode)) - it allows you to set a mask for an image underneath it.

In short, you would create two `SKSpriteNodes` - one with your stamp, the other with your coloured rectangle. Then:

```
SKCropNode *myCropNode = [SKCropNode node];
[myCropNode addChild:colouredRectangle]; // the colour to be rendered by the form/pattern
myCropNode.maskNode = stampNode; // the pattern sprite node

[self addChild:myCropNode];
```

Note that the results will probably be more similar to `CIBlendWithMask` rather than `CIBlendWithAlphaMask`, since the crop node will mask out any pixels below 5% transparency and render all pixels above this level, so the edges will be jagged rather than smoothly faded. Just don't use any semi-transparent areas in your mask and you'll be fine.

Comment: After asking I've saw this solution. I'm still trying to make it work, but it seems that was what I was looking for. Thank your.